# Having Falling block display glass pane that is not just a pole (Java 1.14)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been **trying to make falling blocks in minecraft to show glass panes that contains properties such as north, south, east and west.**
I can get the facing property on commandblocks to work when I display them as a falling block but not on glass pane.

The following shows my attempt to do so

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ {Time:0,BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:glass_pane",Properties:{south:true,north:true}},NoGravity:1}
```

Comment: When I try this, it's incredibly glitchy. From some view angle it almost looks normal and as expected, but from most angles there is something else, for example a gigantic diagonal grey wall with a white top and blue bottom. This is pretty clearly a bug.

Comment: OK, in the latest snapshot EVERY falling block has this problem.

Comment: I created a report: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-161800 But this does not happen in 1.14.4, so that does not answer your question. I also wasn't able to find a report for block states not working. I'll ask in a commands help chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All block states in NBT have string values.

```
Properties:{south:"true",north:"true"}}
```